# CefSharp Chromium 43

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Our Chromium log files are riddled with warnings like this:

> [1007/095721:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(483)] locale resources are not loaded
>   [1007/095721:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(483)] locale resources are not loaded
>   [1007/095730:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(483)] locale resources are not loaded
>   [1007/095730:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(483)] locale resources are not loaded

Does anybody know exactly what they mean?

I have included the en-GB.pak in the installation directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default locale is `en-US`, have you specified `en-GB` explicitly? Does adding `locales\en-US.pak` to your installation directory help?

Is the `en-GB.pak` file in a `locales` directory? by default that's where it's looked for.

Comment: No i havn't specified en-GB anywhere, I'm not sure where to? and it is now in a locales folder, and the errors appear to have gone away.